# Good Answer Badge not awarded for my answer

Tags: support

Per my understanding of the description of the Good Answer silver badge, it is awarded when your answer gets a score of 25 or more

I have score of 25 on 1 answer: [Open a DatePickerDialog on Click of EditText takes two clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267091/open-a-datepickerdialog-on-click-of-edittext-takes-two-clicks/18267997#18267997)

But the badge is not awarded yet. Why?

Comment: The scripts that award badges don't run continuously - please be patient ;)

Comment: Sorry for the spoiler, but you're about to get [another](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) badge as well.

Comment: @Maroun Why do you say that? In addition to being more than a dozen points above the 10pt requirement, it looks like there is another answer posted before OP's was: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18267207/4771017

Comment: @CubeJockey True, I didn't notice that.. Then that's a spoiler for the spoiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it some time.  [Your answer was upvoted to 25 or above 18 hours from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18267997/timeline), and the guiding advice is to give it [about a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1721/175248).

Comment: The post actually was only at a score of 25 for a period of 34 minutes. Don't let the timstamp on the grouped votes of the timeline confuse you. That's all the votes that came in at any time that day, not how many new votes there were at midnight.

Comment: @animuson:  Good to know that it doesn't quite have that resolution then.  (I should've paid a bit closer attention to it, though.)